# Setting onTouchListeners on multiple views

Tags: android

I have created 3 Views in a `LinearLayout` as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/left_scroll">
    </View>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:id="@+id/center_scroll">
    </View>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/right_scroll">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I have created 3 `GestureDetector`s for these 3 views and implemented their methods:

```
class CenterGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
class RightGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
class LeftGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
```

I am trying to do something like this for each of the three:

```
rightView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //What should go here to hook it up to the gesture detector class?

                return false;
            }
        });
//Similarly for other views.
```

In my onCreate method, I have created the following objects:

```
    CenterGestureDetector centerGestureDetector =  new CenterGestureDetector();
    gestureDetectorCenter = new GestureDetector(this, centerGestureDetector);

    LeftGestureDetector leftGestureDetector = new LeftGestureDetector();
    gestureDetectorLeft = new GestureDetector(this, leftGestureDetector);

    RightGestureDetector rightGestureDetector = new RightGestureDetector();
    gestureDetectorRight = new GestureDetector(this, rightGestureDetector);
```

Comment: see if that v in `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` has a id . `v.getID()` .. if it has , then you can manage using switch

Comment: @Vivek_Neel  What should I switch? I'm setting the touch listeners on each of the views individually.